# change permissions to a directory to 701

Tags: unix

I'm supposed to change permission to a ~ directory to 701, thing is this is a web programming class and I know nothing of unix. I managed to get remote access and I can execute commands, so can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `chmod` command to change the permissions. The command you want is most likely:

```
chmod 701 ~
```

Where `701` is the permission level you want to set, and `~` is the directory (or file) you want to apply the permission to.

You may need to apply this permission to subdirectories as well (for example, any `public_html` or similar directory). That is done in the same way.

[Here is the `man` page for chmod.](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) On Unix systems, you can use the `man` command to learn what a specific command does, and how to use it.

Comment: **NOOOOOOOOOOO!** You **don't** want `-R` in this case; it'll change the permissions of everything in your home directory to 0701, which is almost certainly not what you want! Apply permissions *selectively.* // cc @user3541786

Comment: For reference, "normal" permissions are: `0644` for world-readable files not meant to be executed directly; `0755` for world-readable directories and world-executable files; `0600` for private files not meant to be executed directly; and `0700` for private directories and private executable files. You can mix and match permissions bits to make more esoteric permissions sets (0701 is one such example), but those are the ones you are most likely to commonly use in practice.